# convert post title to image

Tags: images, title

Im trying to convert the post title to an image.
i created a php file in the theme folder image.php
with the code
UPDATE: working code

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php');
$postid = $_GET["postid"];
$string = get_the_title($postid);
$im = imagecreate(100, 30);
$bg = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$textcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 255);
imagestring($im, 5, 0, 0, $string, $textcolor);
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

and i call the file with

```
<img src="url/wp-content/themes/v2/image.php?postid=<?php echo $post->ID ?>" />
```

ok now to my problem: the image gets created but without the post title.
Do i need to include anything else to get the_title to execute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### In General

The problem here is that you're calling a WordPress function within a PHP file where WordPress isn't loaded.

Including WordPress in your `image.php` file might work if you include the post ID

```
<img src="/wp-content/themes/v2/image.php?post_id=123" />
```

But imagine if you have 100 images on a single page, then you would be running 101 instances of WordPress!

You might try to hook into WordPress and run only minimized version of WordPress, but then we are still running PHP for each of those images.

Another approach would be to avoid any WordPress calls in your `image.php` file and grab only the title text:

```
<img src="/wp-content/themes/v2/image.php?title=Hello+World!" />
```

But here the danger is that anyone could create an image with any kind of text. That's not good. You could add restrictions, like checking the referrer, but that might not be "watertight".

Better approach might be to create the image files when the post title is modified. Then we can simply call the image file with:

```
<img src="/wp-content/uploads/titles/image-123.png" />
```

but with things like browser caching, we might need a cache buster:

```
<img src="/wp-content/uploads/titles/image-123.png?last-modified=1445683693 " />
```

We might also use the post title in the image file name:

```
<img src="/wp-content/uploads/titles/image-hello-world.png" />
```

The only thing here is we would need to generate those images for old posts.

Let's take a closer look at the last mentioned approach.

### Implementation

Let's assume we have the GD image package installed on our server. Then we could extend the `WP_Image_Editor_GD` class to our needs:

```
class WPSE_Image_Editor_GD extends WP_Image_Editor_GD
{
    private $wpse_bgclr;
    private $wpse_txtclr;
    private $wpse_txt;

    public function wpse_new( $width = 0, $height = 0 ) 
    {
        $this->image = imagecreate( $width, $height );
        return $this;
    }

    protected function wpse_color(  $red = 0, $green = 0, $blue = 0 )
    {
        return imagecolorallocate( $this->image, (int) $red, (int) $green, (int) $blue );
    }

    public function wpse_textcolor( $red = 0, $green = 0, $blue = 0 )
    {
        $this->wpse_txtclr = $this->wpse_color( (int) $red, (int) $green, (int) $blue );
        return $this;
    }

    public function wpse_bgcolor( $red = 0, $green = 0, $blue = 0 )
    {
        $this->wpse_bgclr = $this->wpse_color( (int) $red, (int) $green, (int) $blue );
        return $this;
    }

    public function wpse_text( $text ) 
    {           
        $this->wpse_txt = imagestring( $this->image, 5, 0, 0, $text, $this->wpse_txtclr );
        return $this;
    }

}
```

Here we prefix our methods with `wpse_` to avoid possible name collisions in the future.

It's also handy to return `$this` for *chaining*.

We can get the current upload path with:

```
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
```

and to set the upload path for the generated title *.png* files, we could use:

```
$file = sprintf( '%s/wpse_titles/image-%s.png', 
    $upload_dir['basedir'], 
    strtolower( sanitize_file_name( $post->post_title ) ) 
);
```

This would save the *Hello World* title to the file:

```
/wp-content/uploads/wpse_titles/image-hello-world.png
```

We could use the `save_post_{$post_type}` hook to target a specific post type updates.

But don't want to generate it on each update, so let's check if it's a file that already exists with:

```
if( is_file( $file ) )
    return;
```

Now we can use our custom class and create an instance:

```
$o = new WPSE_Image_Editor_GD;
```

and create an empty image object, color it, add the post title string to it and then save it:

```
    $result = $o
        ->wpse_new( 300, 60 )              // Width x height = 300 x 60
        ->wpse_bgcolor( 0, 0, 255 )        // Background color as Blue
        ->wpse_textcolor( 255, 255, 0 )    // Text color as Yellow
        ->wpse_text( $post->post_title )   // Hello World
        ->save( $file, 'image/png' );      // Save it to image-helloworld.png
```

### Output Example

Here's an example how the *image-helloworld.png* image would look like:

[image: hello world]

### Demo plugin

Here we add it all together in a demo plugin:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name:   WPSE Title Images
 * Description:   On post update, create a png file of the post title (/uploads/wpse-titles/)
 * Plugin Author: Birgir Erlendsson (birgire)
 * Plurin URI:    http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/206433/26350
 * Version:       0.0.2
 */
add_action( 'save_post_post', function( $post_id, $post )
{
    // Ignore auto save or revisions
    if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) || wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id ) )
        return;

    if( class_exists( 'WPSE_Image_Editor_GD' ) )
        return;

    // Get the current upload path      
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

    // Generated file path
    $file = sprintf( 
        '%s/wpse_titles/image-%s.png', 
        $upload_dir['basedir'], 
        sanitize_key( $post->post_title ) 
    );          

    // Only create it once
    if( is_file( $file ) )
        return;

    // Load the WP_Image_Editor and WP_Image_Editor_GD classes 
    require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-image-editor.php';
    require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-image-editor-gd.php';

    // Our custom extension
    class WPSE_Image_Editor_GD extends WP_Image_Editor_GD
    {
        private $wpse_bgclr;
        private $wpse_txtclr;
        private $wpse_txt;

        public function wpse_new( $width = 0, $height = 0 ) 
        {
            $this->image = imagecreate( $width, $height );          
            return $this;
        }

        protected function wpse_color(  $red = 0, $green = 0, $blue = 0 )
        {
            return imagecolorallocate( $this->image, (int) $red, (int) $green, (int) $blue );
        }

        public function wpse_textcolor( $red = 0, $green = 0, $blue = 0 )
        {
            $this->wpse_txtclr = $this->wpse_color( (int) $red, (int) $green, (int) $blue );                
            return $this;
        }

        public function wpse_bgcolor( $red = 0, $green = 0, $blue = 0 )
        {
            $this->wpse_bgclr = $this->wpse_color( (int) $red, (int) $green, (int) $blue );             
            return $this;
        }

        public function wpse_text( $text ) 
        {           
            $this->wpse_txt = imagestring( $this->image, 5, 0, 0, $text, $this->wpse_txtclr );
            return $this;
        }

    } // end class

    // Generate and save the title as a .png file   
    $o = new WPSE_Image_Editor_GD;

    $result = $o
        ->wpse_new( 300, 60 )              // Width x height = 300 x 60
        ->wpse_bgcolor( 0, 0, 255 )        // Background color as Blue
        ->wpse_textcolor( 255, 255, 0 )    // Text color as Yellow
        ->wpse_text( $post->post_title )   // Hello World
        ->save( $file, 'image/png' );      // Save it to image-helloworld.png

}, 10, 3 );
```

We might then create our own template tag, to display the image for each post:

```
if( function_exists( 'wpse_title_image' ) )
    wpse_title_image( $default_url = '' );
```

Here's an example, but in a proper plugin structure, we should be able to remove the duplicated code presented here:

```
/**
 * Get the current post's title image 
 *
 * @param string $default_url Default image url
 * @return string $html Html for the title image
 */
function get_wpse_title_image( $default_url = '' )
{
    $post       = get_post();
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $dirname    = 'wpse_titles';

    $file = sprintf( 
        'image-%s.png',
        strtolower( sanitize_file_name( $post->post_title ) ) 
    );

    $file_path = sprintf( 
        '%s/%s/%s',
        $upload_dir['basedir'], 
        $dirname,
        $file
    );      

    $file_url = sprintf( 
        '%s/%s/%s',
        $upload_dir['baseurl'], 
        $dirname,
        $file
    );          

    if( is_file( $file_path ) && is_readable( $file_path ) )
        $url = $file_url;
    else
        $url = $default_url;

    return sprintf( 
        '<img src="%s" alt="%s">', 
        esc_url( $url ),
        esc_attr( $post->post_title )
    );
}
```

Then you can define the following wrapper:

```
/**
 * Display the current post's title image 
 *
 * @uses get_wpse_title_image()
 *
 * @param string $default_url Default image url
 * @return void
 */
function wpse_title_image( $default_url = '' )
{
    echo get_wpse_title_image( $default_url );
}
```

### Notes

This demo could be extended further, like:

- take this into a proper plugin structure
- adjusting the handling of the *width* and *height* of each title image.
- auto generate images for all posts
- do this for other post types
- ... etc ...

Comment: thanks for your answer. your first suggestion isnt working even if i include the postid it doesnt show the title. second should work but my goal is to hide the title in source code. i guess the other solutions seems to be much more complicated

Comment: I wouldn't recommend loading WordPress for each image. You have to adjust your GET variables in your script. You're also not using any cache in your script. I think I would choose to generate the title image when the post's title is modified. It might be a little more code, but I think it's worth it ;-) @user3646085

Comment: im failing to get it done this way and you suggest doing it more complicated, i dont even know where to start :D

Comment: I updated the answer with an example plugin @user3646085

Comment: hey thanks for the work. did you tested it? i just did, added the code to functions file, called the wpse_title_image function and updated a post. It doesnt display anything

Comment: yes this demo is tested. I was going to leave the `wpse_title_image()` definition up to you, so it wasn't included. But I updated the answer with such an example. @user3646085

Comment: just tested it returns just <img src="" alt="post title">

Comment: Did you save that post first? Also check your /uploads/wpse_title/ directory. It works on my install. @user3646085

Comment: i was a little bit busy..tested again works great now thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome, glad to hear it worked for you. @user3646085

Comment: just wondering if you have knowledge in jquery specially jplayer soundcloud api etc. just looking for someone who can integrate soundcloud streams into my exisitng jplayer code (not for free for sure)

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't worked with SoundCloud API in jplayer ;-) Best of luck with the project @user3646085

Answer (score 0):

I think in image.php, post Id is blank, and so not getting anything. moreover - is this the only code in image.php? You need to make sure WordPress system gets loaded before calling get_the_title & pass postid from caller to image.php like - image.php?pid=223

Load Wordpress at the top of your image.php file:

```
require('./wp-load.php');
```

Grab the postid from URL param:

```
$postID = $_GET['pid'];
```

Then rest of your code goes as is.

When calling this script in image tags src, make sure to pass the correct pid

```
src="image.php?pid=xxx"
```

Comment: i edit my post i missed the first 2 lines. i already had both lines in it still doesnt work.

Comment: Can you print the output of what it gets as postid and get_the_title call? Perhaps use error_log and paste the log here

Comment: nothing in the logs. the image gets created but without the title

Comment: Log won't be automatic ... Do yourself a favor - error_log($postID); error_log($string);

Comment: Or simple print and exit after that to see what it gets

Comment: still nothing in the log

Comment: If you do error_log('sdddfahd') - is that appears is log?  Or simply print the parameter is you sent and exit - then it should show the ID nothing else

Comment: 2015/10/24 07:49:07 [error] 8669#0: *34 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: 
PHP message:" while reading response header from upstream, client: , server: , request: "GET /wp-content/themes/v2/image.php?postid=113439 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "", referrer: "https:///"

Comment: I think you get the problem yourself now. Your code is looking for $_GET['id'] but you are sending image.php?postid  - change code to $_GET['postid'] . The main point is - make sure you are passing the and grabbing correct postid before calling get_the_title ... W/o this nothing else can help you - forget wp, this is Basic URL parameter grabbing

Comment: even if i change it still doesnt work and i get the same error

Comment: ok got it your comment got me to look over the code i had postID while everywhere else i had it lowercase postid. works now thank you

Comment: Your problem is not with the wp title reading and making image - if you can't make the simple get parameter access in PHP scripts. what about just  having an image with displaying your postid get param?

Comment: Finally, glad you found it :)